# Get Order Data in Event Listener in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento

I'm trying to get order details in ***checkout_submit_all_after*** event.

My Observer class is

```
<?php
namespace Cloudways\EventsObservers\Observer\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Data implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
       $order = $observer->getOrder();

    }
}
```

How can I get order data like Customer address, phone number etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it

```
$orderData = $order->getData();
```

It returns order data as array